# Connecting to a squid proxy that uses the openvpn profile set up on that machine

Tags: linux, http, proxy, squid

ive been battling with this the last few days, im trying to set up a squid http proxy that i can connect to, and all that traffic is from a vpn.

Host Machine Application request ----> Squid Proxy -------> VPN -------> Internet (Then response back from here via same route)

I am unsure how to do this however, as far as im aware my configuration is correct, but it must not be due to the service not being contactable.

Please help

```
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
#include /etc/squid/conf.d/*
#auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
#auth_param basic realm proxy
#acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.20
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
#ttp_access allow authenticated
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128
tcp_outgoing_address 10.7.7.4
# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

I've tried adding authentication but had issues with that.

When i do a

```
admin@truenas[~]$ curl -v -x http://192.168.0.35:3128 http://www.google.com/
*   Trying 192.168.0.35:3128...
* connect to 192.168.0.35 port 3128 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 192.168.0.35 port 3128: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.35 port 3128: No route to host
```

It seems to fail, i can ping both the vm and the host machine, both ways so they can definitely contact eachother. Its probably something silly im missing.

Have cross posted this to superuser, so apologies if thats against any rules